# run time error 1004 and 424

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a problem offsetting my range variable.

i have 2 different sheets, one with the original sheet, and one sheet for making the "print version".

```
dim r as range

Set r = printSheet.Range("c100")

For loopcounter = 97 To 1 Step -1
    If r > 0 Or r.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Or _
         r.Offset(0, 2) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 4) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 6) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 7) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 8) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 9) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 10) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 11) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 12) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 13) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 14) > 0 Or _
        r.Offset(0, 15) > 0 Then

    Else: r.EntireRow.Delete

    End If
        'this code fails with runtime error 1004
    Set r = printSheet.Range(r).Offset(-1) 
        'this code fails with runtime error 424
    set r = r.offset(-1)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Set printSheet = ActiveSheet

    For loopcounter = 97 To 1 Step -1
        Set r = printSheet.Cells(loopcounter, "C")
        If r > 0 Or r.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 2) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 4) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 6) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 7) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 8) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 9) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 10) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 11) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 12) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 13) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 14) > 0 Or _
            r.Offset(0, 15) > 0 Then
        Else
                r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next loopcounter
End Sub
```

The problem with your code is that it destroys the **Range** variable!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move 1 row up you should give both parameters:

```
Set r = r.offset(-1,0)
```

or write it like that:

```
Set r = r.Offset(rowOffset:=-1)
```

EDIT:

The second problem is that this line:

```
r.EntireRow.Delete
```

Deletes `r` range, so `r` is empty. To avoid it you can for example:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim DeleteRow As Boolean

Set r = Sheet14.Range("c100")

For loopcounter = 97 To 1 Step -1
  DeleteRow = Not (r > 0 Or r.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 2) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 4) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 6) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 7) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 8) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 9) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 10) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 11) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 12) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 13) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 14) > 0 Or _
     r.Offset(0, 15) > 0)
  'first move up
  Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
  'delete row if needed
  If DeleteRow Then r.Offset(1, 0).Delete
```

Comment: even with the 
    set r = r.offset(-1,0)
it gives the run-time error 424 (object required)

Answer (score 0):

can you please check what is the value of '**loopcounter**' variable and what is the address of the range '**r**' when error came.

i think there no cell up to go to.